# Reporting Service: Change reports based on format

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a report that will be viewed from SSRS report manager and scheduled to send a flat file as well. The problem is that the rich display, summation rows, and some other elements that are perferred when viewing the report online or as a PDF are not wanted when the report is viewed in Excel or when it is exported to CVS. The solution I proposed was to simply have two reports. One that was nicely formated and the other that was more of a raw data feed but they want only one report meaning that I need a way to show one thing if it is viewd online or saved to a PDF and something different when it is saved to CVS or XLS. Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: Is the report being run on a SSRS 2008 R2 Server?

Answer (score 0):

When exporting to .csv format, many fields are stripped. Have you looked at what the existing functionality does to your report?

If that's not adequate, you can use the new SSRS 2008R2 global variable to change item visibility. For example set the hidden function to:

```
=(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL")
```

This would hide something when exported to Excel format. (This is only available since SSRS 2008 R2.)

More info on this at:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2010/05/02/globals-renderformat-aka-renderer-dependent-report-layout.aspx